# Big Query System Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep getting system error while using window functions with 'PARTITION BY'

It seems to work if 'PARTITION BY' or 'LIMIT' is removed

Will someone be able to help with this? Thanks!

> Error: System error. The error has been logged and we will
>   investigate.
>
> Job ID: 719125837414:job_BD8OOBietML6_Y197QhtAHDz_Yk

```
SELECT id, date, Label1, amount, 
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY date, Label1 ORDER BY amount DESC) r
  FROM (SELECT id, date, Label1, SUM(Label2) amount
          FROM [table]
          GROUP EACH BY 1,2,3) LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: How large are the partitions?

Comment: The job id I have post, there are more than one million rows. It's still doesn't work even I have narrowed it down to 5,000 rows. Plus, it runs if I take out 'limit 10000.' Don't think it's a size issue.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at it, and I can confirm it is a bug in BigQuery. The workaround is to remove unused SUM() and grouping key from the inner query, i.e. the query you posted in the question actually works, but the one which triggered the error had extra unused SUM(FLOAT(Label2))/100.0 and IF(col1 IS NULL,col2,col1) col2 in the inner SELECT. Once I removed them - query passed.